# Making a PHP table of images

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Ok I know this has been asked but I feel my situation is a little different and unique. I have my php and html code merged together and it is making  a table 9 images long instead of 3 by 3. Also a secondary problem if someone is kind enough to help me out I am looking to format all the pictures to the same size to make the table look better any help is appreciated.

Here is my table file

```
<?php 
// Get our database connector
require("includes/conn.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>

    <div>

        <?php   
            // Grab the data from our people table
            $sql = "select filename from people LIMIT 9";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());
            $count = mysql_num_rows(result);
            $i = 0;
            $per_row = 3;
            echo '<table><tr>';

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

            echo "<td><img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br /></td>";

            if(++$i % $per_row == 0 && $i > 0 && $i < $count) {
                # Close the row
                echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
        }

            for($x = 0; $x < $per_row - $i % $per_row; $x++) {
             echo '<td></td>';
            }
            echo '</tr></table>';


        ?>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows(result);
```

instead of:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Here's a working simulation, with an array instead of mysql calls: http://codepad.org/Fyv2mIvS

Comment: Thanks for the response I appreciate it Im going to look at it in the am

Comment: Just putting the money sign helped a lot. I need to work on size and structure but I will figure it out. I believe that money sign was a large part of my problem. Thank you

Comment: the extra loop is for filling up the remaining cells in the last row.

Comment: Was able to get it going with your guys help I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a close curly in the wrong place.  You're closing the whole `while` loop right after the check to see if you need to close the table row.

Comment: No dice but thanks for looking Im gonna look more in the morning and figure this out